# Basel problem approximation error to specific sum

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, riemann-zeta

Does anyone have proof that is worth (or not) or suggestion to this?

Let be $S_n \in \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}$ ($\zeta(2)$ approximation), then

$$
    \left|S_n - \frac{\pi^2}{6} \right| < \frac{1}{n}
$$

and

$$
    \left|S_{n-1} - \frac{\pi^2}{6} \right| > \frac{1}{n}
$$

Comment: Think about integrals.

Comment: Using the Abel-Plana' formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula
$$|S_{n-1}-\zeta(2)|=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac1{k^2}=\int_n^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2}+\frac12\frac1{n^2}+4n\int_0^\infty\frac x{(e^{2\pi x}-1)(x^2+n^2)^2}dx$$
$$<\frac1n+\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{n^3}\frac{\zeta(2)}{\pi^2}$$

Comment: Use $\dfrac1{n(n+1)}<\dfrac1{n^2}<\dfrac1{n(n-1)}$ to get bounds on the series remainder.